# AdMob banner ads showing blank in iOS app

Tags: swiftui, admob

I am developing an iOS app with SwiftUI but I am having issues with AdMob banners.
While developing and testing the ads I used the test AppID and AdUnitID, and all is working correctly. The banner ad shows up correctly in the simulator and when I run locally on my iPhone.
I then set the AdMob AppID and AdUnitID to my own (not the test ones) to submit my app to the App Store. When people download my app from the App Store, the banner just shows blank.
I created my AdUnitID in AdMob almost a week ago, but the banners are still showing up blank.
Any suggestions on what I could be missing or doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Google AdMob is your app linked to the App Store?
I have 3 apps in the App Store.  None have ads.  I have test ads appearing in a new dev version of one of my Apps.  The previous version has been in the App Store for over a week.
Via Google Admob when I search for the App in the App Store it does not find it.  It is able to find my other two Apps that have been in the App Store for a longer period of time.
I'm waiting to be able to link the App to AddMob before I put the new version in the App Store.